# Very slow SOAP POST request processing with ModSecure for certain rules (SQL, IIS and system exploits)

Tags: nginx, mod-security, performance

While trying to implement NGinx WAF with ModSecurity 3.0.6 I am facing the issue with very poor XML SOAP POST performance. Rrequests takes ~5 seconds with occasional spikes up to 10 seconds.

If I disable the following set of ModSecurity CoreRuleset rules, then page response is within 0.6-0.8 seconds: 942360 932150 932115 932100 932110 932105 942190 941170. Obviously disabling IIS, MSSQL and Windows exploit protection when exactly that is on the backend does not sound like a right way to do it. :)

This list was somehow obtained via systemtap script. The above rules with v3.0.4 were performing 1000-10000 times slower than rest of the rules! "Somehow", because after server was reinstalled with prebuild packages same systemtap [script](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx/blob/master/ngx-modsec.stp) does not work. If I run `stap -l 'process("/opt/modsecurity/libmodsecurity.so*").*'`  there is no ".function" string in the output.

The issue was spotted with ModSecurity 3.0.4 (with responses up to 20 seconds!) and I have tried to do debug on a host. During that time I have downloaded 3.0.6 version and compiled ModSecurity, NGinx connector for specific NGinx version, using default config options (following NGinx [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/)). At some point it looked, like the update to 3.0.6 have resolved this issue as responses were down to 0.6-0.9 second, which seemed acceptable. So it was decided to rebuild host, update pipeline and rebuild packaged. After rebuild, I still see responses averaging at 5 seconds.

So either I might have missed something, either it is expected performance. It is also quite possible, that during frantic testing attempts I might actually have run tests on server with removed above rules and was happy with "upgrade". :)

Host: Azure Standard D2ds v4 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)
NGinx: nginx-1.18.0-2.el7.ngx.x86_64 (tried with 1.20 but performance was even worse)
OS: CentOS 7.8
CoreRuleset: 3.0.2, 3.1.2. 3.3.2 no significant difference observed

XML request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310" xmlns:stuf="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <BG:npsLv01-prs-NatuurlijkPersoon xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310 bg0310_msg_prs.xsd" xmlns:StUF="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301" xmlns:BG="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/bg/0310" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <BG:stuurgegevens>
            <StUF:berichtcode>AAAA</StUF:berichtcode>
            <StUF:zender>
               <StUF:organisatie>xxxx</StUF:organisatie>
               <StUF:applicatie>YYYY</StUF:applicatie>
            </StUF:zender>
            <StUF:ontvanger>
               <StUF:organisatie>xxxx</StUF:organisatie>
               <StUF:applicatie>DDS</StUF:applicatie>
            </StUF:ontvanger>
            <StUF:referentienummer>123455555</StUF:referentienummer>
            <StUF:tijdstipBericht>11111111</StUF:tijdstipBericht>
            <StUF:entiteittype>NPS</StUF:entiteittype>
         </BG:stuurgegevens>
         <BG:parameters>
            <StUF:sortering>0</StUF:sortering>
            <StUF:indicatorVervolgvraag>false</StUF:indicatorVervolgvraag>
            <StUF:maximumAantal>1</StUF:maximumAantal>
         </BG:parameters>
         <BG:gelijk StUF:entiteittype="NPS">
            <BG:inp.bsn>123456789</BG:inp.bsn>
         </BG:gelijk>
         <BG:scope>
            <BG:object StUF:entiteittype="NPS">
               <BG:inp.bsn xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:geslachtsnaam xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:voorvoegselGeslachtsnaam/>
               <BG:voorletters/>
               <BG:voornamen/>
               <BG:aanduidingNaamgebruik xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:geslachtsnaamPartner/>
               <BG:voorvoegselGeslachtsnaamPartner/>
               <BG:aanhefAanschrijving xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:voornamenAanschrijving/>
               <BG:geslachtsnaamAanschrijving/>
               <BG:adellijkeTitelPredikaat xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:geslachtsaanduiding xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:geboortedatum xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:inp.geboorteplaats/>
               <BG:inp.geboorteLand xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:overlijdensdatum xsi:nil="true"/>
               <BG:verblijfsadres>
                  <BG:aoa.identificatie xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:wpl.identificatie xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:wpl.woonplaatsNaam/>
                  <BG:gor.openbareRuimteNaam/>
                  <BG:gor.straatnaam/>
                  <BG:aoa.postcode xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:aoa.huisnummer xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:aoa.huisletter xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:aoa.huisnummertoevoeging/>
                  <BG:inp.locatiebeschrijving/>
               </BG:verblijfsadres>
               <BG:sub.correspondentieAdres>
                  <BG:wpl.woonplaatsNaam/>
                  <BG:postcode xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:aoa.identificatie xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:gor.openbareRuimteNaam/>
                  <BG:aoa.huisnummer xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:aoa.huisletter xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <BG:aoa.huisnummertoevoeging/>
               </BG:sub.correspondentieAdres>
               <BG:sub.telefoonnummer/>
               <BG:sub.faxnummer/>
               <BG:sub.emailadres/>
               <BG:acd.code/>
               <StUF:extraElementen>
                  <StUF:extraElement naam="String"/>
              </StUF:extraElementen>
               <BG:inp.heeftAlsNationaliteit StUF:entiteittype="NPSNAT">
                  <BG:gerelateerde StUF:entiteittype="NAT">
                     <BG:code xsi:nil="true"/>
                     <BG:omschrijving/>
                  </BG:gerelateerde>
               </BG:inp.heeftAlsNationaliteit>
            </BG:object>
         </BG:scope>
      </BG:npsLv01-prs-NatuurlijkPersoon>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you show us the request that you sent to the server? A `curl` example would be fine.

I tried with this command: `time curl -vvv "http://localhost/upload.php" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "data=@your_soap.xml"`, but it ran 0.076 secs. In that environment, I run Nginx+libmodsecurity3+CRS 4.1/dev on PL4. The total number of evaluated rules is 878. For more investigation, I need the complete request.

Comment: In SOAP UI I do see the following in request. Not sure how to do it via curl, with all XML, mTLS content. :) But I can try.

```POST https://HOSTNAME/app/path HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "soapActionOnbekendTestRoeland"
Content-Length: 4281
Host: HOSTNAME
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)```

Comment: Right - and can you try this curl command, is this still slow?
`time curl -vvv "http://your.url/upload.php" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf8" -X POST -d @soap.xml` where soap.xml is your file?

Comment: Btw I got this result:
`*   Trying ::1:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf8
> Content-Length: 3974
> 
* upload completely sent off: 3974 out of 3974 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
real 0m0,088s
user 0m0,007s
sys 0m0,004s`

Comment: With curl I am getting the following results:
* first request some times takes 1-3 seconds, but usually is fast.
* subsequent requests 0,4-0,6 seconds

SOAPUI is constantly getting response in 4,5-5 seconds. I have set up all the headers and compared Modsecurity log entried for both CURL and SOAPUI requests. They seem to be identical, however content lengtt differs. Curl: 4196, SOAP: 4281

It looks like SOAP inserts something different into that XML, but I have looked into SOAP UI http log and pulled XML content from there.

Comment: I have traced the issue down to payload type. When I have updated ModSecurity to log request I have noticed that curl have stripped line endings, while SOAPUI passed file as is, i.e. with CRLF's. 

if I updated curl options to use --data-binary instead of -d, I started to get same behavior: response time jumped to the same 4-5 seconds and I see nginx process using 100% CPU core time while request is being processed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back soon and investigate the issue.

Comment: Hmm... I just can reproduce your issue partially. I tried the `curl` command above, replaced the `-d` by `--data-binary`, then the response time became 1.5 secs from 0.08 secs. I saved the the soap.xml with CRLF, tried with that, then if gone back to 0.08 secs. Original xml content still processed about 0.08 secs too. I have 8 CPU's, but I'm sure it does not count now. I have no idea now.

Comment: What you can do is try to remove the files under `CRSROOT/rules/` one by one. I mean you can start it with REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf (keep the previous files as there are): remove it, restart Nginx, try to send the request. If problem still exists, put it back and remove the next one. If the problem solved, please let me know what file was that.

Comment: Rules 954130 949110 911100 were removed due to false positives. Removal of REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP, RESPONSE-952-DATA-LEAKAGES-JAVA, RESPONSE-953-DATA-LEAKAGES-PHP has not significantly reduced response. Removing 3 rules (932100 932150 932105) to exclude Unix vulnerability scan reduces response time to 2,3-2,4 sec. Excluding REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE further reduces time to 2,0 sec from 2,3-2,4sec. Excluding REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI further reduces time to 0,6 sec from 2,3-2,4sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136245/discussion-between-airween-and-elvinas).